# Can't connect to MongoDB deployed from MongoDB Cloud Manager to AWS

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services

I used MongoDB Cloud Manager to Deploy a DB Cluster.

I have **one cluster** that contains **3 shards** and in each shard has a replicaset with 3 `mongod`

There are also 3 Config servers and 1 mongos

So I have in Total 9 Hosts for the `mongod` in Total

It look like this

```
Cluster
-- Shard 0
---- P
---- S
---- A
-- Shard 1
---- P
---- S
---- A
-- Shard 3
---- P
---- S
---- A
```

First I want to know how to connect to the whole cluster? do I just connect to the `mongos` or add them all to the `mongodb_url` like this

```
mongodb://user:pass@host1:27000,...host9:27000/dbname?replicaSet=dbcluster
```

Do I have also to add the `mongos` host and `config server` hosts?

I tried all possibilities but I always receive "No reachable host"